# Why primitive types can be cast to object

Tags: java

I wondering why and how does this code work. 
Primitive types are not extends Objects so why this works ?

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double rndValue = 232;
        showObj(rndValue);
    }
    public static void showObj(Object obj)
    {
        System.out.printf(obj.toString());
    }
}
```

Please explain this as detailed as possible. Thank everyone in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Java language feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) called [*boxing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) that allows a primitive type to work with a reference-type parameter, variable, or collection. The compiler will generate proper code to obtain<sup>1 a `java.lang.Integer` in your case.</sup>

The disassembly makes this clear:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #2                  // double 232.0d
       3: dstore_1
       4: dload_1
       5: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
       8: invokestatic  #5                  // Method showObj:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      11: return
```

At instruction 5, the compiler generates a call to `Double.valueOf(double)` which is used to actually obtain the necessary object.

1 The word *obtain* is used in lieu of *construct* as the object may be cached. Due to immutability, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on here -- a boxing conversion (`double` to `Double`) and a reference widening conversion (`Double` to `Object`).  When `showObj` is called and `rndValue` is assigned to `obj`, an assignment conversion takes place, and a boxing conversion followed by a reference widening conversion is explicitly allowed by the [JLS, Section 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - **a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening reference conversion**
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

It's converting the `int` to an [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), which is an object.  This process is called [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).